# Matplotlib Patch Size in Points

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I draw shapes in matplotlib using point/inch dimensions?

I've gone through the patch/transform documentation so I understand how to work in pixel, data, axes or figure coordinates but I cannot figure out how to dimension a rectangle in points/inches.

Ideally I would like to position a rectangle in data coordinates but set its size in points, much like how line markers work.

Here is an example of the plot I am trying to create.  I currently position the black and red boxes in (data, axes) coordinates.  This works when the graph is a known size, but fails when it gets rescaled as the boxes become smaller even through the text size is constant.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib). You could do the transform at the end.

Comment: I've attached some pictures showing the problem.  I suppose I could read the figure size and calculate what portion of the axes would represent a certain number of inches but that seems very fragile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up figuring it out with help from this question: [How do I offset lines in matplotlib by X points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839468/how-do-i-offset-lines-in-matplotlib-by-x-points)

There is no built in way to specify patch dimensions in points, so you have to manually calculate a ratio of axes or data coordinates to inches/points.  This ratio will of course vary depending on figure/axes size.

This is accomplished by running a (1, 1) point through the axes transform and seeing where it ends up in pixel coordinates.  Pixels can then be converted to inches or points via the figure dpi.

```
t = axes.transAxes.transform([(0,0), (1,1)])
t = axes.get_figure().get_dpi() / (t[1,1] - t[0,1]) / 72

# Height = 18 points
height = 18 * t
```

[image]
[image]